# Transit between ferries on Tenerife

Tags: transit, spain, ferries, canary-islands, tenerife

I'm planning to take a ferry from Gran Canaria to Tenerife and then Tenerife to La Palma on 21 December. The ferry from Gran Canaria arrives at Tenerife 17:00, and the ferry to La Palma departs at 19:00. But: there is 80 km between the ferry terminals. Both ferries are operated by the ferry company Fred. Olsen and they sell the journey as a single entity. Does anyone know, or can anyone infer from [their website](http://www.fredolsen.es), whether they offer a transit between the ferries to ensure connection? It's very tight (if at all possible) with regular scheduled buses (based on Google Maps information), so otherwise I'd need to take a taxi.

**UPDATE 6 October 2012**: In the new timetable, the ferry to La Palma departs at 20:00 rather than 19:00, whereas the ferry from Gran Canaria arrives at the same time. So travellers have three rather than two hours, which makes the usage of [regular buses](http://www.titsa.com/) much more feasible.

Comment: Zooming in on google maps it shows the ferry paths, and it would appear there are two on the routes you want where the terminals are much closer together - are you sure that's your only option?

Comment: Can't say yet for sure, as the timetables for the Christmas period are not finalised yet. But in the present timetable, it appears only Trasmediterranea has ferries Las Palmas – Santa Cruz de Tenerife – Santa Cruz de La Palma, but only on Thursdays, whereas Fred Olsen has daily ferries Las Palmas – Santa Cruz de Tenerife and Los Cristianos – Santa Cruz de La Palma. As I arrive on a Friday, I can't use the former option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes, there is.** However, information on internet is quite poor, therefore I describe my own experiences here.

On 21 December 2012, I travelled from [Gran Canaria airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gran_Canaria_Airport) via [Las Palmas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Palmas), [Agaete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agaete), [Santa Cruz de Tenerife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Cruz_de_Tenerife) and [Los Cristianos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Cristianos) to [Santa Cruz de La Palma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Cruz_de_La_Palma). The ferry company [Fred Olsen](https://www.fredolsen.es/) operates many [ferry-bus](http://www.fredolsen.es/en/services/ferry-bus) connections. I will describe my experiences below.

The airport bus from Gran Canaria has two stops in Las Palmas: San Telmo and Santa Catalina. *Neither bus-stop is serviced by the ferry-bus*, but rather the bus leaves from the Fred Olsen office close to El Corte Inglés, which is in turn close to the *second and last bus-stop* of the airport bus. Personally, I was in a hurry, and only just made it by running up the escalator, across the square and around a block, asking a few times for the way. In the ferry office, show your ferry reservation and you will get a ticket for the bus. The bus goes straigt to the Gran Canaria – Tenerife ferry.

[image: ferry-bus at Agaete]
Ferry-buses at Agaete, Gran Canaria.

Upon arrival at Santa Cruz de Tenerife, **there is a ferry-bus connecting with Los Cristianos** departing 20 minutes after arrival of the ferry. The bus waits for a delayed ferry and the next ferry waits for a delayed bus. If you have a through-ticket Gran Canaria – La Palma (or La Gomera, or El Hierro), this connection is guaranteed.

[image: Ferry-bus at Santa Cruz de Tenerife]

Ferry-bus at Santa Cruz de Tenerife, connecting with the ferry to La Palma.

[image: ferry-bus timetable photo]

Photo of timetable of ferry-bus at Santa Cruz de Tenerife.

Comment: Glad you had better experience with busses/transport and thank you for sharing it.